# Strike through string PowerPoint interop

Tags: c#, interop, office-addins

I have 2 PowerPoints one original and one edited. I each PowerPoint I have a textbox that contains a number of words. The idea is to find any words added or deleted from the original PowerPoint in the edited and put them in a list. I then want to put a strike though these words that have been added or deleted but I can't access any of the properties I need as I have a string and not a TextFrame. Any ideas how I could strike through the words? E.g  original "This Text" edited "This New Text" outcome "This <strike>New</strike> Text".

My code is as fallows

```
        List<int> originalShapesListID = new List<int>();
        List<int> editedShapesListID = new List<int>();
        List<int> originalListID = new List<int>();
        List<int> editedListID = new List<int>();
        List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> originalList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
        List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> editList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShpID;
        List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape> originalListWords = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape>();
        List<char> editListWords = new List<char>();
        editedShpID = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape originalShpID;
        long editedShapeID;
        long originalShapeID;
        editedShapeID = 0;
        originalShapeID = 0;
        originalShpID = null;
        originalShp = null;
        editShp = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextFrame txtFrame;
        char delimiter = Convert.ToChar(" ");
        List<string> one = new List<string>();
        List<string> two = new List<string>();
        int indexOfWord = 0;
```

Getting all Text

```
    String pps = "";

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in Originalslides)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape originalShape in slide.Shapes)
        {
            originalShp = originalShape;
            if (originalShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                var textFrame = originalShape.TextFrame;
                if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                    pps += originalShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                    foreach (char word in pps)
                    {

                        l.Add(word);
                        Debug.WriteLine(word);
                    }


                }
            }
            originalShapesListID.Add(originalShape.Id);
            originalShapeID = originalShape.Id;
            originalList.Add(originalShape);
        }

        originalListID.Add(slide.SlideID);
    }

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide in EditedSlides)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editShape in slide.Shapes)
        {
            editShp = editShape;
            if (editShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {

                var textFrame = editShape.TextFrame;
                if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                    pps += editShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                    foreach (char word in pps)
                    {

                        l.Add(word);
                        Debug.WriteLine(word);
                    }


                }
            }

            editedShapesListID.Add(editShape.Id);
            editedShapeID = editShape.Id;
            editList.Add(editShape);




        }

        editedListID.Add(slide.SlideID);


    }
```

Checking if there is an added or deleted word

```
    var q = from original in originalList
            join editedTmp in editList on original.Id equals editedTmp.Id into g
            from edited in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                original,
                edited
            };



    //foreach  through both lists
    foreach (var item in q)
    {


        List<string> diff;

        var originalString = item.original.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
    var editString = item.edited.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;

    var firstStringList = originalString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

    var secondStringList = editString.Split(delimiter).ToList();

        if (secondStringList.Count() > firstStringList.Count())
        {
            diff = secondStringList.Except(firstStringList).ToList();
            //change to blue for added word

        }
        else
        {

            diff = firstStringList.Except(secondStringList).ToList();


            // change to red for deleted word
        }
```

}